# How can we show that $\Phi\left(-\frac b{2\sqrt a}\right)+e^{\frac{a-b}2}\Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right)$ is uniformly bounded in $a,b$?

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, normal-distribution

Let $\Phi$ denote the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution. How can we show that $$\Gamma(a,b):=\Phi\left(-\frac b{2\sqrt a}\right)+e^{\frac{a-b}2}\Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right)\;\;\;\text{for }(a,b)\in(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R.$$

> How can we show that $\Gamma$, $\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial b}$ and $\frac{\partial^2\Gamma}{\partial b^2}$ are bounded (in both arguments)?

**EDIT**: Note that $$\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial b}(a,b)=-\frac12e^{\frac{a-b}2}\Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right)<0\tag1$$ and $$\frac{\partial^2\Gamma}{\partial b^2}(a,b)=\frac14\left(e^{\frac{a-b}2}\Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right)-\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}\right)\tag2$$ for all $(a,b)\in(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R$. By $(1)$, $$\mathbb R\ni b\mapsto\Gamma(a,b)\tag3$$ is decreasing for all $a>0$ and since $$\Gamma(a,b)\le\Phi\left(-\frac b{2\sqrt a}\right)+\frac 2{\sqrt{2\pi a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}\xrightarrow{b\to-\infty}1\;\;\;\text{for all }a>0\text{ and }b\le a,\tag4$$ we conclude $$\Gamma(a,b)\le1\;\;\;\text{for all }(a,b)\in(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R.\tag5$$

> What can we do for $\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial b}$ and $\frac{\partial^2\Gamma}{\partial b^2}$?

Comment: $\Phi$ decays like $e^{x^2}$ towards minus infinity. You have to take this into account

Comment: @tst What exactly do you mean by "decays like $e^{x^2}$"? $\Phi$ is a cdf, so it takes values in  $[0,1]$.

Comment: I think he just forgot a minus sign: the CDF of a gaussian has a tail bound of the form $P(Z < b) \leq e^{-\frac{b^2}{2}}$ for any $b < 0$, so as $b$ gets negative, that coefficient will be dominated by how tiny the CDF is.

Comment: @E-A Okay, I get that if $X\sim\mathcal N_{0,\:1}$, then $\operatorname P\left[X>x\right]\le e^{\frac12\lambda^2-\lambda x}$ for all $\lambda>0$ and $x\in\mathbb R$. I guess that's what you mean. Especially, $\operatorname P\left[X>x\right]\le e^{-\frac{x^2}2}$ for all $x>0$. How can we use this for the desired claim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$, then obviously $f$ and $g$ are both unbounded, so their product is also unbounded. The only problem with this reasoning is that the product is $f(x)\cdot g(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^x}$, which is bounded. Do you see what went wrong here?

Let's go back to your original question. Let fix $b=0$, then the function $e^{a/2}$ is unbounded, however for big $a$, $\Phi(\sqrt{a})$ behaves like $e^{-a/2}$, which compensates for the growth.

In generall if $a-b>0$, then $\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\le0$. This means that $\Phi(\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a)$ can be bounded by something like $e^{\frac{b-a}{2}-\frac{b^2}{8a}}$, which means that the product is bounded. Of course what I've written here is not a proper proof, but this is the essense of the proof. You need to find a precise bound for $\Phi(x)$ when $x<0$ and then check that it decays faster than $e^{\frac{b-a}{2}}$.

---

Let's assume that $a-b>0$, $\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a>0$ and $\sqrt a >0$ (this last one is a reasonable assumption, but still it is an assumption that is needed). Then we have
$$ \frac{b}{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a>0 \implies b-2a>0 .$$
Now we take $b-2a>0$ and $a-b>0$, we add them together and we get $-a>0$ which is a contradiction. So $a-b>0$ implies $\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a \le 0$ (or $\sqrt a <0$ which is a case that needs to be discussed).

This mean that when the "problematic" exponent $a-b$ is positive, $\Phi$ compensates for this growth.

---

The general method for the derivatives is to establish that they are continuously differentiable and then control the growth to infinity. Because of the exponential convergence to some value, the derivative converges exponentially to 0. This implies that it is bounded.

In your case the issue is simpler. Just differentiate, $\Phi$ has a nice derivative. However, unless there is some relation you haven't mentioned, the derivatives you've written are wrong (I may be wrong here).

You have to be careful what is actually you are asking for. When you differentiate with respect to $b$ you get $\sqrt a$ in the denominator. This means that the derivative is unbounded close to $a=0$. The derivatives are bounded only if you fix $\varepsilon>0$ and ask that $a>\varepsilon$. (this is not true if the derivattives are correct)

---

I am assuming here that (1) and (2) are correct. In this case they are bounded.

If you know how to prove that $\Gamma$ is bounded, then (1) is also bounded as it is just the problematic term that was discussed above.

For (2) you need to show only that $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}$ is bounded. The only region this can be problematic is $a\to0$ as then $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi a}}$ goes to infinity "polynomially" fast (with exponent $1/2$). However, if$a\to0$, then $-\frac{b^2}{8a}$ goes to infinity polynomially fast (with exponent 1) so $e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}$ goes to $0$ exponentially fast. This dominates and the product goes to $0$.

This last argument follows from the fact that $x^{-1}e^x$ goes to infinity as $x\to\infty$ (you can show this using the Taylor series).

---

OK, fine, I will write the steps clearly.

First you should check that for all $x<0$ there exists $M>0$ such that $\Phi(x) \le M e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$.

Let's define $f(a,b) := e^{\frac{a-b}2}\Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right)$.

Let's check that $f$ is bounded. We have two cases:

1. $a-b\le0$ means that $e^{\frac{a-b}2}$ is bounded so $f$ is bounded.
2. $a-b>0$ means that $\frac{b}{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a \le 0$ (assuming that $\sqrt a>0$) so we use the bound and get
   $$ \Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right) \le M e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}+\frac{b-a}{2}}. $$
   This means that $$ e^{\frac{a-b}2}\Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right) \le M e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}. $$

From the above we deduce that $f$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R$.

Observe that $\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial b}(a,b)$ is just a constant times $f(a,b)$, which means that $\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial b}(a,b)$ is bounded.

Similarly $\frac{\partial^2\Gamma}{\partial b^2}(a,b)$ is a constant times $f(a,b)$ plus a constant times $a^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}$. Let $c=1/a$, then $$a^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}} = c^{1/2}e^{-\frac{b^2c}{8}}.$$
Convince yourself that the LHS is bounded for every $a\in(0,\infty)$ if and only if the RHS is bounded for every $c\in(0,\infty)$. For every $b$ the RHS is analytic on $(0,\infty)$, so it is bounded on $(0,N)$ for every $N>0$. Then check that the limit at infinity is 0. This proves that the RHS is bounded.

Comment: @0xbadf00d I have added some more information.

Comment: (a) I've just checked the calculation of $(1)$. It should be correct. Why do you think it is wrong? (b) I'm asking for boundedness in both arguments. For $\Gamma$ itself, this is given by $(5)$. If it's not possible for $\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial b}$, then it would be enough for me if we could show boundedness on $(\varepsilon,\infty)\times\mathbb R$, for all $\varepsilon>0$. It seems like you know how we can do that. Could you provide details?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I was wrong about the problem around $a=0$. As $a\to0$ the exponents also go to infinity and the exponential dominates. So there is no problem with that. I may also be wrong about the derivative. I didn't try to simplify everything. So don't take my word for it. If the derivaties are correct, then you are done.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why I'm done? I didn't get your argument.

Comment: @0xbadf00d is it clear now?

Comment: I've proved that $Γ$ is bounded by noting that $\frac{\partial Γ}{\partial b}<0$ and hence $b↦Γ(a,b)$ is decreasing. By this observation, it's clear that we only need to check if $Γ(a,b)$ has a limit as $b\to-\infty$. And that's what I've done in $(4)$. However, I guess that this immediately yields $0\le e^{\frac{a-b}2}\Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right)=\Gamma(a,b)-\Phi\left(-\frac b{2\sqrt a}\right)\le1$. So, $(1)$ is indeed bounded and it's sufficient to check that $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}$ is bounded for $(2)$. But I don't know what you mean by "polynomial fast".

Comment: @0xbadf00d you can just check the limits $a\to0$ and $a\to\infty$ and since it is analytic in between, it is bounded if the limits are finite.

Comment: I guess the reason is that $e^{-x}\le1$ for all $x\ge0$ and hence $e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}\le1$. So, as you say, the only crucial region is $a\to0+$. Let's conclude. From my second to last comment and $(1)$, we obtain $\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial b}(a,b)\in\left[-\frac12,0\right)$ for all $(a,b)\in(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R$. Can we say something similar for $\frac{\partial^2\Gamma}{\partial b^2}(a,b)$?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't think I can explain it any more that what I added now

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations, but do you think anything is wrong with my proof of $0\le e^{\frac{a-b}2}\Phi\left(\frac b{2\sqrt a}-\sqrt a\right)=\Gamma(a,b)-\Phi\left(-\frac b{2\sqrt a}\right)\le1$ and $\frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial b}(a,b)\in\left[-\frac12,0\right)$? The reason is that we can just choose $M=1$. All I wanted to know is whether we can given an explicit bound for $\frac{\partial^2\Gamma}{\partial b^2}(a,b)$.

Comment: From what we know we only need to consider $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}$ and it's clear that this expression is $\le1$ for all $a\ge\frac1{2\pi}$ and $b\in\mathbb R$. So, we only need to consider $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}$ for $a\in\left(0,\frac1{2\pi}\right)$ and $b\in\mathbb R$ and I'm pretty sure that this is $\le1$ as well.

Comment: I hadn't the opportunity to think about this problem for a while, but I still think that your proof of $\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi a}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{8a}}$ being bounded for $a\in\left(0,\frac1{2\pi}\right)$ is wrong. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3293090/47771.

Comment: @0xbadf00d you are right. What I said above holds for $b>\epailon$ for any positive $\epsilon$

Comment: So, $\frac{\partial^2\Gamma}{\partial b^2}$ is bounded on $(0,\infty)\times[\varepsilon,\infty)$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, right? Shouldn't the same argumentation yield boundedness on $(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R\setminus\left\{(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\right\}$ for all $\varepsilon>0$?